# Import css and sass files nextjs 7

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4, next.js

I want be able to import in any file in my project the two types of files.

```
    import 'styles/index.scss';
    import 'styles/build/_style.css'
```

Its important to note im using Nextjs 7 and webpack 4 (comes with nextjs7)

In Nextjs 6 we used to use in next.config.js

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')

const commonsChunkConfig = (config, test = /\.css$/) => {
  config.plugins = config.plugins.map(plugin => {
      if (
          plugin.constructor.name === 'CommonsChunkPlugin' &&
          plugin.minChunks != null
  ) {
      const defaultMinChunks = plugin.minChunks;
      plugin.minChunks = (module, count) => {
          if (module.resource && module.resource.match(test)) {
              return true;
          }
          return defaultMinChunks(module, count);
      };
  }
  return plugin;
  });
  return config;
};

module.exports = withCSS(withSass({
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
      config = commonsChunkConfig(config, /\.(sass|scss|css)$/)
      return config
  }
}))
```

Comment: the easiest solution is to rename `_style.css ` into `_style.scss` and use sass loader. Why doesn't it work for you? :)

Comment: the problem is that there are some packages that has it own `style.css` and i just need to import it not change the package core.

Comment: ok i see. I added an example setup that work for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UDDATE March 2020**

Nextjs v9.3 Add support for sass as well. More info [here](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#built-in-sass-support-for-global-stylesheets)

**UPDATE January 2020**

Nextjs v9.2 Added native support for CSS. More info [on official docs](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-2)

> To get started using CSS imports in your application, import the CSS file within pages/_app.js.
>
> Since stylesheets are global by nature, they must be imported in the Custom  component. This is necessary to avoid class name and ordering conflicts for global styles.
>
> If you are currently using @zeit/next-css we recommend removing the plugin from your next.config.js and package.json, thereby moving to the built-in CSS support upon upgrading.

---

This basic example works for me with having `next-sass` and `next-css` side by side

**/next.config.js**

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS(withSass());
```

**/pages/index.js**

```
import '../styles.scss';
import '../styles.css';

export default () => {
  return (
    <div className="example-sass">
      <h1 className="example-css">Here I am</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**/styles.css**

```
.example-css {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

**/styles.scss**

```
$font-size: 50px;

.example-sass {
  font-size: $font-size;
}
```

**/package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
  "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
  "next": "^7.0.2",
  "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
  "react": "^16.6.3",
  "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
}
```

Here is [what I see on the screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/epqid7tfjqkom91/Screenshot%202018-11-15%2000.19.44.png?dl=0)

Hope this helps!

PS there is [some info](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3852) on official GitHub repo as well

Comment: Greate! i just had to update my css/sass/next dependencys and works! Thank you

Comment: Any idea how I can deploy this to zeit-now? What should I put into now.json? Thanks

Comment: I just tried and see that there is some issue with deploying next/css and next/sass to now v2. Here is an issue I face as well https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5750#issuecomment-443562606

Comment: facing this issue constantly, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

I initialized my project like this includes SCSS CSS PNG SVG TTF.

```
 npm install withSass@canary withCSS@canary node-sass

//next.config.js

const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS(withSass({
webpack (config, options) {
   config.module.rules.push({
       test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
       use: {
           loader: 'url-loader',
           options: {
               limit: 100000
           }
       }
   });

    return config;
    }
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `next-compose-plugins`.

It provides a cleaner API for creating `next.js` configurations, you DONT need to install `@zeit/next-css` and you ALSO DON'T have to do any `webpack loader` configuration to make it work.

Here is an example with the `@zeit/next-source-maps` plugin for demo purposes:

```
/* Import modules */
const withSourceMaps = require( '@zeit/next-source-maps' );
const withSass = require( '@zeit/next-sass' );
const withPlugins = require( 'next-compose-plugins' );

/* Configuration */
const NextAppConfig = ({
  // config stuff goes here, no webpack loader config required
})

/* Export declaration */
module.exports = withPlugins([ 
  [ withSourceMaps ],  
  [ withSass ]
], NextAppConfig );
```

I prefer to declare the array before the export because it is even cleaner setup:

```
// ... imports go here

/* Plugins array variable */
var plugins = [ [ withSourceMaps ], [ withSass ] ];

/* CONFIGURATION */
const NextAppConfig = ({
  // Config stuff goes here, no webpack configuration required
})

/* EXPORT DECLARATION */
module.exports = withPlugins( plugins, NextAppConfig );
```

https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-compose-plugins

Answer (score 0):

For those with an external package (in node_modules) here's a Working CSS+SASS solution on next 9.3.0. It involves a standard import of the CSS via SASS. This example uses videojs:

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "next": "^9.3.0",
    "next-absolute-url": "^1.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "video.js": "^7.7.5"
  },
```

next.config.js:

```
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
module.exports = withSass({
  assetPrefix: process.env.NEXT_BASE_PATH || '',
  exportTrailingSlash: true,
  exportPathMap: function() {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' }
    };
  }
});
```

component "VideoPlayer.jsx" requiring external CSS

```
import './VideoPlayer.scss';
```

VideoPlayer.scss:

```
@import '~video.js/dist/video-js.css';
```